# Get XML element attribute with simplexml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have a xml file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<shop version="2.0" shop-name="XYZ">
 <category name="FOO1">
  <subcategory name="Foobar1">
     <product name="Productname1" id="1">
        <supplier name="XXX" logo="XXX.gif" />
        <desc>DESC</desc>
     </product>
     <product name="Productname2" id="2">
       ...
     </product>
  </subcategory>
 </category>
</shop>
```

And i would like to get attribute value of shop element - exactly shop-name

I used simplexml in php:

```
<?php
    $dataXML=simplexml_load_file("data.xml");
    $a=$dataXML->shop[0]["shop-name"];
    echo $a;
?>
```

as a result I get nothing. Have any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are attributes, so you need to access them correctly with `attributes()` method:

```
$data = simplexml_load_file( 'data.xml' );
$attributes = $data->attributes();
echo $attributes['shop-name'];
```

Or you can access it directly, since it's the `main attribute`:

```
$data = simplexml_load_file( 'data.xml' );
echo $data['shop-name'];
```

Answer (score 2):

use the **getAttribute()** methdo to read attribute name.

```
<?php
    $dataXML = simplexml_load_file("data.xml");
    $shopName = $dataXML->getAttribute("shop-name");
    echo $shopName;
?>
```